# Get entity's property value in different format (GAE-Python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, referenceproperty

In google app engine
When i try to get propery value by ReferenceProperty element
It return referenced entity value in different format Like:
real stored value "Name" : "demoname"
when i get and print/write: u'demoname

is there any function or way to get value in proper string format.
code:
person model has name property:
o_model = model()
o_model.ref = personmodel reference #db.ReferenceProperty(person)
now i get model entity object:
sro.write(modelobject.ref.name)
output:u'namevalue
wanted:namevalue

Answer (score 1):

If `modelobject.ref.name` is a [StringProperty](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#StringProperty), then it is "[returned by the datastore as a unicode value](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#str)."

The `u'` looks like the [repr()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#repr) of a `unicode` object:

```
>>> s = u"Unicode String."
>>> print s
Unicode String.
>>> print repr(s)
u'Unicode String.'
```

Perhaps `sro.write()` calls `repr()` or you're storing the `repr()` of a Unicode string in the datastore?

Comment: same thing try with entity object i got perfect result. but when try with referenceProperty it return in this unicode format.